# Symfony2 assetic cause javascript error

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig, assetic

I have a problem, I'm there two days without being able to solve it:

I have a page with twig using javascripts, prod and gives error on the page, does not give error on dev

I tried using assetic and gives error

I've tried taking the asset files from the web, also gives error

the base file: http://pastebin.com/Xyjg0U0L

the page the error: http://pastebin.com/Vj73EuPk

dev.itenho.com.br/

dev.itenho.com.br/app_dev.php

I've compared the two versions of html and css in ubuntu meld and is identical

Comment: can you describe the error a bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just can guess since your error description is a bit vague.

But this is a "classic" one when you have errors with assetic in your prod env:
You can do two things:

Try to add in your config_prod.yml:

```
assetic:
    use_controller: true
```

or call:

```
php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved it with a semicolon ; at the end of the js file. Check all your js file and put a semicolon ; at the end of those file that no has one.